# C# Whats the utility of an Anonymous Type/Anonymous class?

Tags: c#, anonymous

They are readonly, they are local and they have a few requirements... Whats their advantage vs doing the same "with name"?

I know this might seem stupid for some people, but I cant find the answer anywhere.

var ThxForYourAttention = new {Name = "asd", IdNum = 1};

Comment: They're useful if you need to group data together as you process it through a method, but don't want to declare a normal named type for it.

Comment: I use them often, when I need to transform data into a specific structure - but only at a single place. E.g. you have your `class User` with `Name` and `Lastname`. However, an api needs a user json with `FirstName` and `LastName` field. You could then create anonymous objects with the fitting field names and pass them to a json serializer.

There is no real disadvantage in creating a `class` except having "more code` and the slight danger someone might get confused, because he doesn't know what this class is meant for.

Comment: They are automatically comparable based on their data contents. `new{A="" }.Equals( new{A=""}` is true. `new Person{Name="Bill"}.Equals(new Person{Name="Bill"})` is false unless Person overrides Equals - and who wants to to that every single time they want to search for or group something in LINQ?

Comment: @Dominik an api needs a user json with FirstName and LastName field - you can decorate the properties of User with e.g. `[JsonProperty("FirstName")]`.. Though you'd probably not send your internal classes for ser' - you'd have a set of models you use with the API, and map your internal classes to/from them, perhaps with automapper. Doing `JsonConvert.Ser(new { FirstName = u.Name })` could be considered primitive mapping, but might be a bit of a maintenance headache because it's per-location

Comment: @CaiusJard I don't agree with putting `JsonProperty` annotations on my `User` class. It's A) not the right place to do so (why do I have 3rd party api specific things in my data class?) and B) not a flexible solution at all.  

What if I need to send my user objects to another api, that has other fields? However, using the `JsonConvert` functionality would be a good solution. Anyways, it's just a sample for OP to get the grasp of a potential use case.

Comment: You have different user objects. Note that I said "can", not "should"

Comment: @CaiusJard Thats up to me, since it's my sample I guess :-) Anyways, your point with providng a mapping function to the `JsonConvert` is a good way.